# Why did the Institute pick Shaun?

Tags: fallout-4

My question is why do the institute pick Shaun. Could they not have picked anyone else?

I mean they could have taken the guy you control in the game instead of Shaun or one of the other vault dwellers. Why Shaun?

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: @close voter, how is this developer intent?

Comment: Question and title are a bit spoilery. We don't actually know that the kidnappers are associated with the institute until we get a ways into the main quest.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is explained in the game - they were after an individual who hadn't already been exposed to the radiation of the wastelands. This is covered early on during conversations with Shaun after arriving at the Institute, when you get the "But Why?" dialogue option.

> **Father:** ...You believed that ten years had passed. Is it really so hard to accept that it was not ten, buy sixty years? That is the reality. And here I am. Raised by the Institute, and now its leader.
>   *Select "But Why?" dialogue choice*
>   **You:** But why? Why take a child? Why take you?
>   **Father:** Ah, now that's the question isn't it? "Why me?". At that time, the year 2227, the Institute had made great strides in synth production. But it was never enough. Scientific curiosity, and the goal of perfection, drove them ever onward. What they wanted was... the perfect machine. So they followed the best example thus far - the human being. Walking, talking, fully articulate... capable of anything.
>   *Select "They needed specimens" dialogue choice*
>   **You:** So the weird science experiments needed specimens. That's why they took you.
>   **Father:** In a manner of speaking, yes. The Institute endeavored to create synthetic organics. The most logical starting point, of course, was human DNA. Plenty of that was available, of course, but it had all become corrupted... in this... wasteland... radiation affected everyone. Even in their attempts to shield themselves from the world above, members of the Institute had been exposed. Another source was necessary. But then the Institute found me, after discovering records from Vault 111. An infant, frozen in time, protected from the radiation-induced mutations that had crept into every other human cell in the Commonwealth. I was exactly what they needed. And so it was my DNA that became the basis of the synthetic organics used to created every human-like synth you see today.

Comment: Oh ok. But I have another question. Why not choose the main character as there was no nuke when he lived in the house in sanctuary before the nuke forced them into the vault? Sorry if the question seems irrelevant and already explained as I don't understand yet.

Comment: @BatmanRekstNubs Kellogg refers to the main character as the "backup", so presumably they were going to if something happened to Shaun.

Comment: @colorfusion oh ok but another thing were all the other vault dwellers dead? Could the institute take them if both Shaun and the main character died?

Comment: @BatmanRekstNubs They were killed by Kellogg as to not leave any more witnesses.

Comment: @colorfusion It was my understanding that the rest of the vault dwellers died from cryo failure. Is there any indication that Kellogg killed them?

Comment: Hm. The main char wasn't less exposed to radiation than Shaun, right? But yeah... if you can chose, a child may make more sense.